# What is the effect of default initialization for a union instance?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14

Following [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), I would understand that the behaviour until C++11 is to leave it uninitialized (if the union is a POD type, which is likely), while it would call a default constructor anyway starting with C++14.

Is this statement correct ?

**EDIT**: I am puzzled because in C++ Primer (5th edition, covering C++11), one can read "Like the built-in types, by default unions are uninitialized" (p 848), but a bit further, there is "... the union (member) will have been default-initialized, meaning that the first member of the union will have been initialized" (p 851).

It seems contradictory to me, saying that by default unions are uninitialized, then saying that default initialization of a data member that is a union would initialize the union's first member.

Comment: What has the link to do with unions?

Comment: @KerrekSB my understanding would be that unions are classes (potentially of POD-type), and the link explains "The effects of default initialization" in the case of non-POD classes (and implicitly of POD classes).

Comment: Default initialization in C++ includes no initialization for 'char', 'int', ...

Answer (score 3):

For any class type `T`, default-initializing an object of type `T` attempts to find and run a default constructor. If a union contains any member with a non-trivial constructor, the union's default constructor is defined as deleted if you don't define one explicitly (9.5/2), and thus the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Does that hold true even if the `union` is a POD type ? In which case, do you have a clue why would C++ Primer 5th state that "...by default unions are uninitialized" ?

Comment: @AdN: POD implies trivially constructible, non (and in fact *trivial*)?

Comment: @Barry ["Either a ScalarType Or a class type (class or struct or union)"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType), treating of PODType seems to contradict you extract.